# Hibernate bi-directional access and illegal access to loading collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an issue with bidirectional access via a jointable, which works in one direction and not in the other. I've had to anonymise the definitions but hopefully everything significant is still there. The scenario is:

MASTER is the main table which has a one-to-one mapping with two tables A_SECTION and B_SECTION which are sub-sections of the master record and all three share a common ID. This is an existing configuration which has worked for years.

I've added a TIA_TIB_SHARE table which represents a many-many relationship between two rows in the MASTER table - this links the A_SECTION on one with the B_SECTION on another. Both relationships are identical as far as I can tell, but while access from a MASTER through an A_SECTION to another MASTER via the jointable works, if I access a different row from the B_SECTION side I get an "illegal access to loading collection" error. I've tried implementing lazy loading without any success.

Can anyone provide any suggestions as to why this works in one direction and not in the other, or what steps I could take to diagnose this? I've extracted the relevant bits of the Hibernate mapping file below - all the mapping is in XML and there are no annotations used.

Thanks in advance...

```
<class name=”Master” table=”MASTER” where=”is_deleted=’N’”>
<id name=”id” column=”ID” type=”long”>
<generator class=”native” />
</id>
<one-to-one name=”sectionA” class=”SectionA” />
<one-to-one name=”sectionB” class=”SectionB” />

</class>
<class name=”SectionA” table=”A_SECTION” where=”is_deleted=’N’”>
<id name=”id” column=”ID” type=”long”>
<generator class=”native” />
</id>
<one-to-one name=”master” class=”Master”
constrained=”true” />
<set name=”shared” sort=”natural”>
<key column=”TIA_ID” />
<one-to-many class=”Share” />
</set>
</class>

<class name=”SectionB” table=”B_SECTION” where=”is_deleted=’N’”>
<id name=”id” column=”ID” type=”long”>
<generator class=”native” />
</id>
<one-to-one name=”master” class=”Master”
constrained=”true” />
<set name=”sharing” sort=”natural”>
<key column=”TIB_ID” />
<one-to-many class=”Share” />
</set>
</class>

<class name=”Share” table=”TIA_TIB_SHARE”>
<id name=”id” column=”ID” type=”long”>
<generator class=”native” />
</id>
<many-to-one name=”sharingA” class=”SectionA”
cascade=”all” update=”true” insert=”true” column=”TIA_ID” />
<many-to-one name=”sharedB” class=”SectionB”
cascade=”all” update=”true” insert=”true” column=”TIB_ID” />
</class>
```

Comment: Having done a bit more testing, it appears that the error only occurs if the many-many set contains more than one row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but since I cannot write one:
I don't have a solution but it might make the debugging easier if you put  *not-found="ignore"* and some kind of join explicitly into the many-to-many definition (outer join might work).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I'd pasted the mappings form an existing set and hadn't noticed that I'd retained the sort="natural" clause. However, my test data had one row in the many-many set for one test and two rows for the other. The single row set worked but the multi-row set didn't and this was resolved by implementing equals(), hashCode() and compareTo() on my Share class.

Hibernate was failing to instantiate the collection because the class wasn't Comparable, but this didn't matter when there was only one row. I'm not sure why Hibernate chooses not to reveal this in the stack trace and instead returns the LazyInitialisationException.